# Turning all variables in each row into a percentage of the sum of each row?

Tags: r

I am using the dataframe "death rates in Virginia" for a class project. I need to normalize the data so that they can be compared and analyzed. Is there a way for me to take each row and calculate the percentage of each value from each row instead of doing it manually?
for example if I have a row of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5: I would like to sum do the following to each individual object in the row: x/sum of all objects * 100.
is there a quick way to do this to each row? Thanks

Comment: Have you used `prop.table`? try `prop.table(1:5)` in your console

Comment: take a look at the percentagaes-functions from the `janitor`-package

Answer (score 0):

with base functions

```
dummy_df <- data.frame(a=sample(1:100,20),b=sample(1:100,20),c=sample(1:100,20))

t(apply(dummy_df,1,function(x) {100*(x/sum(x))}))
```